# Aren't Java constructors public by default?

Tags: java, constructor, visibility

I have two classes in two different packages. For one class I've defined a constructor without setting access modifier for it. I want to instantiate an object of this class in another package and get the error '`the constructor xxx() is not visible`'.

If I define access modified to `public` it is fine. I thought constructors are public by default?

Comment: Class constructors are package-private by default. Enum constructors are private by default.

Comment: The only constructor that's public by default is the implicit, no-arguments one. That is if you don't define any.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**no access specifier != public**

No Modifier is package private. check [doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: The answer is OK but the linked doc does not mention of default c'tors.

Comment: @Bob did you see _no modifier_ ?

Comment: but in interfaces all the methods are public abstract even you put public or not

Answer (score 13):

No, they're not. They have package-visibility by default.

Answer (score 8):

Access is (err...) *default access* by default. Also known as *package private*. Consider: if they were `public` by default, how would you indicate that a constructor was not `public` but in fact was package private? There is no keyword corresponding to package private with which to indicate that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use access modifiers in a constructor's declaration to control which other classes can call the constructor. **If you don't declare the constructor explicitly as public it is visible only in the same package where it was declared (package access)**.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't write access modifier it is set to default, which means package private. E.g. no class outside the package can access it.

Answer (score 1):

No. they have the default access specifier.
i.e they have package visibility.

Answer (score 1):

In a class all method without access modifier have package visibility. However, in interfaces methods always have public visibility.