# What is the explicit constructor access modifier?

Tags: java, constructor

Suppose there is a class A. Which of the following two access modifiers is a default one for a constructor?

```
public A()
{
    private A()
    {
         //some code....
    }

    protected A()
    {
         //some code....
    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: If you understand what the access modifiers mean there is no question here, and if you don't you should look them up in the JLS. Not a real question.

Answer (score 6):

It means the exact same thing as modifiers to functions and variables, only now it refers to who can CONSTRUCT an instance of the class.

`public` - any one can call the constructor from anywhere in the code.

`private` - Unable to construct from outside the class - typically used to enable control over who gets to instanciate the class with the use of a static member factory method. A good example of an appication found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/929045/1520364)

`protected` - Like `private` but now inheritance is involved - any subclass factory method can be used because now they can call this constructor.

As @dasblinkenlight mentions, if you **do not specify** any modifier, then they *default* to being [package-private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668922/arent-java-constructors-public-by-default), meaning they are only visible to classes within the package.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you may want to mention the `A() {}` with its *default access* for use by members of the same package.