# KStemmer in Lucene has private constructor

Tags: lucene

I'm trying to use KStemmer, but it has a private constructor, so I can't explicitly call it's stem method. How is it supposed to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are expected to use a [KStemFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/KStemFilter.html), rather than using the stemmer class directly.

Answer (score 2):

Use the KStemFilter instead of KStemmer because KStemmer has contructor with empty access specifier, which means it can't accessible by outside classes check this link [Aren't Java constructors public by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668922/arent-java-constructors-public-by-default)

Here is how to use KStemFilter in java, check the below link

https://github.com/mwsoft/sample/blob/master/solr-filter-sample/src/jp/mwsoft/sample/lucene/filter/KStemFilterSample.java